# Automatically close dialog box on raspbian after dist-upgrade

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am producing a software product which runs on Raspberry Pi.

My users won't have mouse and keyboard connected to Pi.

I want to be able to upgrade the os with cli scripts by using apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade consecutively.

I can do that now but the problem is, after the upgrade is done. It shows this dialog box to user. I want to disable this or be able to click the ok button from the cli with a command. Do you know how can I do that? Or as a solution maybe, I can close/kill all os realted windows/dialog boxes/pop-ups. Do you know a command for this?
Thanks [this is the dialog box shown after dist-upgrade is done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAkew.jpg)